# Type to represent parent having keys of certain type

Tags: typescript, types

I use this code to dynamically assign property of type ChildClass to a ParentClass

```
export type KeyOfValueType<T, U> = {
  [V in keyof T]: T[V] extends U ? V : never
}[keyof T];

class ChildClass {
  public name: string;
}

class ParentClass {
  public child: ChildClass;
}

class Setter {
  public propName: KeyOfValueType<ParentClass, ChildClass>;

  public setProp(parent: ParentClass, child: ChildClass) {
    parent[this.propName] = child; // <== No Error
  }
}
```

If I try to make a "generic" setter, I get an error :

```
class GenericSetter<T, U> {
  public propName: KeyOfValueType<T, U>; // No Error
  public setProp(parent: T, child: U) {
    parent[this.propName] = child; // <== Error U is not assignable to T[{[V in keyof T]: T[V] extends U ? V : never}]
  }
}

class Setter extends GenericSetter<ParentClass, ChildClass> {
  public setProp(parent: ParentClass, child: ChildClass) {
    parent[this.propName] = child; // <== No Error with Parent propName
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is fundamentally a [design limitation, see microsoft/TypeScript#30728](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30728).  The compiler doesn't do much assignability analysis for conditional types that depend on generic type parameters. Maybe this could be improved, but it would cost something in terms of type checker complexity and compile time, and any benefit would only be seen by some fraction of users who specifically do this kind of thing.  So I wouldn't count on it happening.

---

There are two general ways to deal with this: one is to try to find another way to express the type constraints to that the compiler *can* verify your code, and the other is to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to tell the compiler not to worry and that you are vouching for the safety of what you're doing.  In this latter case, you should be very careful that what you are doing actually is safe first.

Notably, your generic setter code is *not* safe:

```
const oops = new GenericSetter<{ a: string }, string | number>()
oops.propName = "a";
const myParent = { a: "bar" };
oops.setProp(myParent, 123);
console.log(myParent.a.toUpperCase()); // no compiler error, but at runtime:
// TypeError: myParent.a.toUpperCase is not a function
```

Your `KeyOfValueType<T, U>` is going the wrong way: it's giving you the keys of `T` from which it's safe to *read* a value of type `U`, but you need the keys of `T` to which it's safe to *write* a value of type `U`.  Therefore you want something like:

```
type KeyOfValueTypeForWriting<T, V> = {
  [K in keyof T]: [V] extends [T[K]] ? K : never
}[keyof T];

class FixedGenericSetter<T, U> {
  public propName!: KeyOfValueTypeForWriting<T, U>;
  public setProp(parent: T, child: U) {
    parent[this.propName] = child; // same error as before
  }
}

const okay = new FixedGenericSetter<{ a: string }, string | number>()
okay.propName = "a"; // error here now
```

Now at least you can only set `propName` to a key safe for writing, and `okay.propName = "a"` is an error because you can't safely write `string | number` to the `a` property of `{a: string}`.

Still, the assignability error inside `setProp()` persists, so let's try to fix it in the two ways I mentioned earlier.  The easiest and least disruptive fix is a type assertion:

```
class FixedGenericSetterAsserted<T, U> {
  public propName!: KeyOfValueTypeForWriting<T, U>;
  public setProp(parent: T, child: U) {    
    parent[this.propName] = child as any as T[KeyOfValueTypeForWriting<T, U>]; // assert
  }
}
```

which clears up the error quickly but places the responsibility for safety on you.  Or you can refactor the types so that there are no unresolved conditional types, like this:

```
class FixedGenericSetterRefactored<K extends PropertyKey, U> {
  public propName!: K;
  public setProp(parent: Record<K, U>, child: U) {
    parent[this.propName] = child;
  }
}

const fine = new FixedGenericSetterRefactored<"a", string>()
fine.propName = "a";
fine.setProp({ a: "okay" }, "works");
```

This also works without error, but your `T` generic type parameter is gone and replaced with `K`, the relevant key(s) of `T`.  It's safer, but you might have some other use case why you need to specify `T` instead of `K` (although type inference can often alleviate that).

Either way should work for you.  Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIHkBmA1AhgGwK4QCrggB5cAaKAVQD4oBeKAbwCgooBtGKASwDsoBreAHskUXAF0AXKPZioEAB7AI3ACYBnClAD8sKFO4QAbhABOjAL6sBIYaLEBuRk4DGGNGo0BhABacMKzzcPBmYoMCwAIwxOZyhuNABbCABCKTVgEx4Ac0dzFyCNAAU0E2VgQPcNJhZwqJioZ19-VKgfPwCC3PzKqABxZVMYgGUIYCUTYjIqEJrI6NiwE0EwADlElKk4RFRMHHxISYpKeygAelOoFcEoAFETJbNZuti1UcKlsAAKMBKyqVIGk0VFJyABKGYsMK-bjAVjAXxqAB0i2WaySsjojXaJ3OUEINDodwemk4Gm4gmAUEqnCy8Si0GA11wrHorBQXF41ls4n+bNkCiUqg05G0UHZ+iMpnMYlCeTyzkE3HSUEEyw0dAMAHc+gNMs4RmNTIR6FS0hlslBzGR0pluFkoAAfOJYBIRUyUT6gxiqsBIlGrda0KAAIjQwccCqVlISIGKpRhQZNaCkwYiJWDlscPqRr2A72WnxjcbKZAAjAAmADMoIjirUggwEERGEEWULsehwERaERjPIYEgJk87ggnprZwu5IaggSYD8pjk90EJjIESwlLQlJMWBhnCSEkYuP2ECJy6kRc73d7gn7g+Hry4ZIpVKgSB3zmAnEVTlAkFg8GQdBsDwAgADFlwAdUyT87UOFBqDoao2A4Hh+CEEQeTYFB+UUZR1DYZkYDEWQdA4CVjDMSwuQwhxumCUDOHkCAVH6Aw9QNcZDmmJDanmMIPjRDZ-22IC9jAyDoOyLjjlCXj6lzfMvh+eNgH+MgsX8EFwSQmpOzhBFkQE9YMUBbEJygNRA1MYl3CgN0kGXCBZQsRhI2VQQ+DQEAgy1KAGKYljdWGUZOKTM1bXtK0LPNO1HWdV13U9b1PJAQzUUDOhQ3DczrOXKBvFMaByU1JxXIKPzGOY1jBn1ELTAAQQ8UwlBUaSITkhYjKSFotkA3YQMgcCTCgzgYKyaTHCePiFI+b5OzU0zNIobTQl0lT9NJNKA3RIMNJUKkNDQbhvNswiAJ2YDjyGkaxukhxzMqZrnLyOiNH8qqgtqw0TAAJQgJA0A-RzWo4AU8KKD5mpALYpmoHi5nqf1BJ6yawgRl43lm5S-igP6FRMEHYfUoEtIhNayg2v0uogEy9tRuUXDrSkkB4aANQgbV3sCtjgu+v6AaB0pWqy60YqyD0vRZgwtsEoMsscKWmxmgswpDDyvIzKLg01Zc+DUYNxycIA)

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer.
KeyOfValueTypeForWriting and link to Typescript issue are really helpful. Have a nice day.